# Laravel domain routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there any specific benefit or reason one might have specified domain in routes file?

```
Route::group(['domain' => iConfig::get('session.my_domain')], function () {...
```

Instead of omitting it completely?

I am working on an app which is already live and I am wondering if I might break something on live server if I remove this group?

There are also subdomain routes present.

Comment: Usually domain are not in route, but you could use system like that to do multi-domain (subdomain, two different domain name following language ...).
iConfig don't look familiar to me, so it's maybe a custom library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Route::domain (Used in Laravel 5.4)or Route::group(['domain' => 'xyz.com'])? are is used when you have a sub domain which can be either dynamic or statc for example:

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
    //
    });
});
```

Comment: I do have subdomains defined like that. But I am wondering if defining static domain like `myapp.com` has a purpose? So without the `{account}` part

Comment: It is not about a problem or not, here as I can see, they are dividing the application in different sub  domains (for example for users part they use a subdomain, for cars a subdomain ..etc). It is about organization.

Comment: They are, but there is also main domain. My question is whether the main domain has to be a group for itself or I can just put it in routes root under no `Route::group()`